# How to render comment in nodelist page in drupal6

Tags: php, drupal

I created a custom module for listing node and use the following code for rendering comment form

```
print comment_render($node->nid);
```

But it is only working for the first node only

Comment: This should be in http://drupal.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

First install and configure "Comment goodness" module - it will allow you to sort comments to display newest first.

Then in your `template.php` create.

```
function THEME_preprocess_comment_wrapper(&$variables) {
  // Remove pager.  
  unset ($variables['content']['comments']['pager']);
  // Leave only latest comment.
  $last_comment_id = reset(element_children($variables['content']['comments']));
  $variables['content']['comments'] = array (
    $last_comment_id => $variables['content']['comments'][$last_comment_id]
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.But I am using drupal6, unfortunately Comment Goddness module is for drupal7